# Why does GNU as add offset to memory write?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

So I was playing around with some assembly today and I noticed when compiling the following code using `as -o foo.o foo.s` I get a different result than I would expect:

```
.section .text 
.globl _start 
.intel_syntax noprefix 
_start: 
    mov rsi, rsp
    mov rdx, 0x1234567890ABCDEF
    mov qword [rsi], rdx
```

.. which compiles to:

```
# objdump -D -M intel foo.o

oo.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   48 89 e6                mov    rsi,rsp
   3:   48 ba ef cd ab 90 78    movabs rdx,0x1234567890abcdef
   a:   56 34 12 
   d:   48 89 56 08             mov    QWORD PTR [rsi+0x8],rdx
```

I was wondering why `as` adds another 0x8 to the memory write (`qword [rsi]` vs. `QWORD PTR [rsi+0x8]`)??!

Comment: I think GAS interprets a bare `qword` as the constant 8 (the size of a qword).  The correct syntax for what you want is `mov qword ptr [rsi], rdx`.  There might be a duplicate question somewhere around here.

Comment: `qword` instead of `qword ptr` is NASM syntax.  GAS unfortunately doesn't error on it, and has this "failure mode" because it allows `123[reg]`